# Property is missing in type which is an interface implemented by class

Tags: node.js, typescript

**Node: 17.7.1**

**Typescript: 4.6.3**

I was working with an older repo on DDD and I came across a Typescript error as I was trying to recreate the code, which I am not understanding how to fix.

The IDE "error" occurs in AfterSomethingCreated class when registering with the code of :
`Events.register(this.onSomethingCreatedEvent.bind(this), SomethingCreatedEvent.name);`

```
Argument of type '(event: Event) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(event: IEvent) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Property 'something' is missing in type 'IEvent' but required in type 'SomethingCreatedEvent'.ts(2345)
```

Class SomethingCreatedEvent implements IEvent interface.  SomethingCreatedEvent also includes a property in addition to the properties from IEvent.  When the property is included, the error is thrown, when taken out, the above error is thrown in the IDE

Code:

**IEvent.ts**

```
export interface IEvent {
    //.....
}
```

**IHandle.ts**

```
export interface IHandle<IEvent> {
  setupSubscriptions(): void;
}
```

**Events.ts**

```
export class Events {
    
    //Methods...

    public static register(callback: (event: IEvent) => void, eventClassName: string): void {
        //Do Stuff
    }

    //Methods...

 }
```

**SomethingCreatedEvent.ts**

```
export class SomethingCreatedEvent implements IEvent {
  //.....
  public something: Something;

  constructor (something: Something) {
    this.something = Something;
    //.....
  }
  //......

  }
}
```

**AfterSomethingCreated  (Where Error Is Occurring)**

```
export class AfterSomethingCreated implements IHandle<SomethingCreatedEvent> {
  constructor () {
    this.setupSubscriptions();
  }

  setupSubscriptions(): void {
    ---> ERROR -> Events.register(this.onSomethingCreatedEvent.bind(this), SomethingCreatedEvent.name);
  }
  private async onSomethingCreatedEvent (event: SomethingCreatedEvent): Promise<void> {
    //Do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: The code as written is not safe, since nothing guarantees that the callback passed to `Events.register()` will be called with anything more specific than just `IEvent`, so you can get runtime errors [as shown here](//tsplay.dev/Nr5vDw) if the compiler allows you to register callbacks that care about a particular type.  If you just want to suppress the error you can play games using *method syntax* instead of arrow function syntax, which checks parameters bivariantly, like [this](//tsplay.dev/N9EJjN).  If you need things to be actually type safe you might have to significantly refactor.

Comment: Let me know if this addresses your question or if you're looking for something else.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the information!  I'll see how to go about refactoring it to make it safer

Comment: @ndyr so do you want me to write up an answer here about why it's not working and how to suppress the error with bivariance?  Or are you looking for the refactoring specifically (in which case the question should probably be [edit]ed to specify this)?

Comment: @jcalz It sounds the best solution would be a refactor to make it more type safe.  I can update the question to specify for this and also the inclusion of what is initially causing the error.

Comment: I think you might need to provide more information then about how the callbacks will be called, otherwise you'll end up with something type safe but unusable.

Comment: Like, [here](https://tsplay.dev/wRRJ1w) is a complete guess as to a refactoring that makes this better.  Instead of class names you use class constructors because `instanceof` checks will convince the compiler that the handler will be applicable without having to consult some out-of-band lookup table of names.  Not sure if that works for you; if so I can write it up, if not, we need more info here.

Comment: @jcalz Looking at the you link, this looks like you are heading down the direction of what I am already doing.  Updating the register method with the extension of IEvent, clears the compiler error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happens because `Events.register()` takes a callback that supposedly accepts any `IEvent` whatsoever.  Thus it should be perfectly acceptable to actually call the callback with the minimal possible `IEvent` (in your case since `IEvent` is an empty interface this is just `{}`, the empty object):

```
public static register(callback: (event: IEvent) => void, eventClassName: string): void {
    callback({}); // <-- look, no error
}
```

On the other hand the `onSomethingCreatedEvent()` method expects that its input will be a `SomethingCreatedEvent`, and so it should be perfectly acceptable for this method to access event properties unique to `SomethingCreatedEvent` objects, like the `something` property (whose value I am assuming is `string`, since you didn't define the `Something` type in your code.  That is, I'm acting as if `type Something = string;`):

```
private async onSomethingCreatedEvent(event: SomethingCreatedEvent): Promise<void> {
    console.log(event.something.toUpperCase());
}
```

But now inside `setupSubscriptions()` you are passing a callback which only accepts `SomethingCreatedEvent` events to `Events.register()`, which is an error:

```
setupSubscriptions(): void {
    Events.register(this.onSomethingCreatedEvent.bind(this), SomethingCreatedEvent.name); // error!
    // -----------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // Argument of type '(event: SomethingCreatedEvent) => Promise<void>' is not
    // assignable to parameter of type '(event: IEvent) => void'.
}
```

And that's an error for good reason.  If you call the code as modified above, you get a runtime error because somewhere we're calling a callback with the wrong input:

```
new AfterSomethingCreated();
// RUNTIME ERROR: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: event.something is undefined
```

---

Since this was existing code, presumably this doesn't actually happen in practice.  There's actually a bunch of existing JavaScript which is technically unsafe this way.  TypeScript checks *method parameters* in a [bivariant](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance) way, meaning that it will allow both safe narrowing and unsafe widening operations.  *Function* parameters are checked more strictly (assuming you have [the `--strictFunctionTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strictFunctionTypes) enabled, which is part of [the `--strict` suite of compiler features](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict)).

If you want to get the more loosely typed behavior, you need to represent the type of `callback` as a *method* instead of a *function*.  By the way, here's the difference:

```
interface Test {
    functionSyntax: (ev: IEvent) => void;
    methodSyntax(ev: IEvent): void;
}
const test: Test = {
    functionSyntax: (ev: SomethingCreatedEvent) => { }, // error!
    methodSyntax: (ev: SomethingCreatedEvent) => { } // okay!
}
```

See how the declaration of `functionSyntax` in `Test` is a property with an arrow function expression type, while `methodSyntax` looks more like a method declaration.  And see how the implementation of `test` complains about the `functionSyntax` property accepting too narrow of a type, while the `methodSyntax` property does not complain.

So if you want to just suppress the error, you can rely on method syntax.  Well, it's a little tricky, because there's no method syntax for standalone functions.  You can't write `(ev: IEvent): void` as a type, and `{(ev: IEvent): void}` is treated like function syntax.  The trick here is to make an actual method type and then [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into the surrounding object:

```
type MethodSyntax = { method(event: IEvent): void }["method"]
// type MethodSyntax = (event: IEvent) => void, but marked as a method
```

And now if you write `Events.register()` with that:

```
public static register(callback: MethodSyntax, eventClassName: string): void { }
```

Then your call will suddenly work with no error:

```
Events.register(this.onSomethingCreatedEvent.bind(this), SomethingCreatedEvent.name); // okay
```

This isn't any more type safe, but at least it's not in error.

---

If you care about enforcing type safety, then you'll probably need to refactor so that nothing bad can happen when a handler handles a callback.  Here's one possible approach:

```
class Events {
    static handlers: ((event: IEvent) => void)[] = [];
    public static register<T extends IEvent>(
        callback: (event: T) => void,
        eventClass: new (...args: any) => T
    ): void {
        this.handlers.push(ev => ev instanceof eventClass && callback(ev));
    }
    public static handleEvent(event: IEvent) {
        this.handlers.forEach(h => h(event));
    }
}
```

Now `Events.register()` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function that accepts a `callback` that only accepts an event of type `T`, and an `eventClass` constructor (instead of a class *name*) for `T`.  This way each handler can be called for each event... we don't call `callback(event)` unless `event instanceof eventClass`.  With just a class *name*, it would be hard for the compiler to verify that any particular event would be appropriate for any particular callback, as the `name` property of classes is not strongly typed in TypeScript (see [microsoft/TypeScript#43325](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43325) and issues linked within for more info).

And then the following is accepted now for `SomethingCreatedEvent`:

```
    setupSubscriptions(): void {
        Events.register(this.onSomethingCreatedEvent.bind(this), SomethingCreatedEvent);
    }
```

while something inappropriate would be flagged:

```
Events.register((o: SomethingCreatedEvent) => { }, Date) // error!
// Property 'something' is missing in type 'Date' but required in type 'SomethingCreatedEvent'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOYAU0HsAjAGwjCQG8AoJWpDYAFwjQDMFkBJAUQDcImlGnREB6UQDopU4bQC+VWfSYt2iJJwASIYABNSAHh78mAPiEiRUCIwCuMAMq3CUeJhiMM+YFAAUASgAuJF58DF0AbiUFJXhiECgoJD4BRiTqJTFRAFkbAAt8XShpRUs6GGdiDHgkKEYQTxq0CCwMOpZfeBBiYkIEAGtg3wgTRmDjVP8kAF5zUPCAGiQR1IBheMSAOXAIYLrMYCwgkLDdCzLLLp6++H7fCjl-CKRxJAMAWnekYnx8fqXgPhlmgCGhMnQYhcXjl8oVijJoqU6HEEkkHPhIIw8gwsKtmg0ILoUoIMGAYKRIEwkhNBNQoeJpDIoRUSNVahj8ji9owDlgouDaPBvPtbPBGPg0L4oBysVzajycVM6VC6LLitLMdjDjN2ZqcVEVXQGYyBUgFPTJIyJEj5DakCjEkgAIKsZhodF6w54iAEs6k8lkVLU7R6Qwezle-HMImjczKspCnw80XiyVK00iNUSax2RzOVzuTzCgIGi6Qi45+xOFxuDAeLw+ALBeZneMq4lpCTNVrtSVZ7zh2WRn3RjsSQgMXS+NX+JaDrW4qOEsegSBPaHA0EAQgzRtESE+h6Pn3MAD9zxfL1frzfbxfd7RXk60FhbJTGEh8KwkIwAJ4wZAAHJhlGYJ5xxb1fQ7KZZiQPAMTaCADBbUxAPoJJAUYB8N1RbBQBIZBxSQOA0B2N1P2-P8AKQYCViYcZoJmOZTkA60oXNC4YEwXgCSQBJf2AGoBxlBdINHUYQNSMCRIgpcY0mYJ4LARDkNOONsMTaVSAkH4sEkphsxkw4JHFABVGAALQVYEggAInlNDjbSUYAIAAd2dV0WHA4dfRLJRXgAJVMzYABVOGybhkgCgKUAC4JTMEkBbCwPIP18BhiIIZTrCmEL-wgbgQQlYI6MYQzPSwdCkFsPQIFYBhCUUGJV2gOB1FyLFCgANRYKAGyEJQGDdNRkBC6APzbERWBqsUGwcAT6gADyGEYGNGGDmPCUsyk1Qp5qYEBFpAtaFJOLbERETSP2YOpgjGuodUmuhpsEotgH2paVt4aSKrE5d1qYygzSWV4WG3U1dt0D7Dq+n6I0XEd-smQGKDNDc-hAX8dxEctaCG1QOA0DtzickR8bYQmtB0fQkJpRh1KhSs8xrQsGz8Y4W22s07So5AOoKKGFsOx6kEh-SxiJ9bm1OM0AG0ACJIflgBdfz915pB+b2oXFp1cWTqYDazt0JZCFsD8wBANB+kJPikhAUXYV0O0HSSDt0lNFkqhqOoGjZbs2jdTpul6AZgi1wWDsWpZSvWVFtkgbleQ5mXUcc7nYg2NEjIRqDRnoMkKSDSXUhJywvbZDV4aT-U7Uu4VkzFCUpRzmvDnTQ1aCzKuh0q6ZdXhrmcbtXH7Szjy3W83PowLgN32Damwxzv75LMMv66TNAU2bjvO+7mwq3zWt62Lez2LrugmerAs6ze9npfCdeLndrsWkDjp+3e5e5LHCc9GnbEUBZxICnivFcOx1yvAxr+ByntuK8X4oJT8X9fo-wkqVOGvcwFSzgllFSKEn62mHk1RQLVYCEwCnVBAqYy7kxGiXWkGdLrj3doQ+Ufsah5EXr1IY+sGGMCNi2fwstlY6hEUPcolRK71EaEgAOvYDAhWWItZgehqQdlML4DSIcbiDCQHwkKgjTgLGwrHLOwQXLuV8NIK2WAoDBB0L+I2IVTQp0fk9MoWYuGhl6hICoUA8ggUBiMZQvtBIQC-MsUYcdHQADJYn2h0QMEC-gz5lk9lIn2Mi2TeJph2PhdNd6Gi8dwtAxRWASm4AgQJeRAaBNKqkiRRCIQu3HqAtBpd-RFypPwthFcfat3lLyJp9oG5bybpKHuC425HDYZmQB5V4Y6imbXc+xDmGognl5b+iNWymiuuM1MAQ5mqgWVfI+rNT4jNHlYA+zMb4n0bG4vZndkijGKPIoOn92m7N-pOABbRgE-LzpMa5cCMA8WYHbASQkUHw2wakPhwLxKnSUvgtSJzBTCnwNpXS4tFm9xMvgcyllrLWDsmC4eIhLFbPdDs3y9lM6bJQFiFgxMPF8SwMgfuAAGLm6cX6fI6ECWCqN8ASBAFygA1FKpYmkcUQB0vgPS4rJUQCmHIJYLK8hsvWvyEQL9cmkHyTS5FSMmC+Hlisw48tGkbgcCgCKIVNCcE2AAcViA3T83KkA0u1bqxFaTaCGu4fk-A6rnivAAIxKBDT4sNEaNwACY7SCrfr2Xwvh8CYNEh0w2KNgZIAACIEimKDIqaBsZ7lwfgSyf4aLWqwGhNoos2h9W1BlDWgES3MDQmbD8zQACOtgMDND9MAH8+UaJmtXowViVAYiuUnPgVyErdCzoADLvxcpKQCNUjWEmaAAKwgLNbwgElgvTPRO8WRTRk+AVRIMGzdAIJQPWcY9p63r6K4ghawwQL1RNSH4vB1gliAfxNKYAAGY6jFfgkbw4H-ASEAvZR4EQgA)